# MongoDB add a field to a embedded document in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

Hello I am new to MongoDB and i have been looking for a way to add a field to a embedded document in an array

// collection

```
> db.test.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5761765a31356152793c8790"),
    "name" : "bb",
    "email" : "bb@mail",
    "projects" : [
        {
            "project_id" : ObjectId("576179bf31356152793c879c")
             //How can i add a name here
        }
    ]
}
>
```

Comment: You want to add same name for both project_id? or specific name for each?

Comment: a different name i just want to be able to access the projects.project_id

Comment: Can you not just do `$set: {"projects.0.name": "foo"}`?

Comment: @slugonamission I tried this `db.test.update({name:'bb'},{$set :{projects.0.name:'foo'}})` and it gives me this error SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out :) 
`db.test.update({projects:{$elemMatch:{"project_id" : ObjectId("576179bf31356152793c879c")}}},{$set :{'projects.$.name':'foo'}},true);`
Hope it helps someone 
Thank you !